# TWO greyboxes for one window? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, greybox

I want to modify a JavaScript function on a (n ASP.NET 2.0) page to show another (different) greybox after the first one has been hidden. Existing snippet:

```
parent.parent.GB_hide (); /* we are done */
```

Fancied enhancement:

```
parent.parent.GB_hide (); /* we are done */
parent.parent.GB_showCenter ('Another One', 'http://google.com'); /* 2nd greybox */
```

This does not work as expected, because

```
GB.use_fx
GB.type
GB.show_loading
```

are all reported to be null or not an object. 
So I suspect that these are global variables and the two
greyboxes are competing for those (but I might be wrong).
Has anybody ever tried this? Two greyboxes for the same 
page?

Kind regards
q

Answer (score 1):

I believe one can achieve it as. Initial call to greybox is like this

```
GB_showCenter('Initital form',url,500,600, closeBack);
```

**closeBack** is the javascript method and is a callback function which is triggered when greybox close event occur. You can call second greybox with in this as

```
function closeBack(){
   GB_showCenter('Second form',url,100,100); 
}
```